# Visual Studio compilation is slow - system has plenty of spare resources

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2015, compilation

When I build a large website in Visual Studio 2015 it takes a long time.  Resource Monitor tells me that CPU, memory, disk and network are only lightly used (CPU about 10%, memory 43% and the others are 0%).

I've looked at some posts and articles about speeding up compilation but they mostly focus on using less resources.  In my case I don't think that would help as I already have plenty of extra capacity that is not being used.

I've tried using 4, 8 and 16 parallel builds and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

For reference I have an i5 processor, 8GB RAM and a SSD drive.

I would like to understand what is preventing the compilation from being faster, and what I can do to a) investigate the problem and b) fix the problem.

Comment: which CPU do you have and which 3rd party extension do you have installed?

Comment: CPU is an Intel i5 4460.  I'm not sure what you mean by 3rd party extension.  I have found that the problem is related to the 'Enable Code Analysis' checkbox on the project build options.  With this box checked the build takes over an hour and then I cancel it out of boredom.  With the box unchecked the build completes in 30 seconds max.

Comment: ok, do you need this all the time at compile? If not disable it and only run it once a day to check your code that you added at end of your work day

Comment: I have indeed disabled it.  However, my question is as much about why this process is taking so long when all those resources of my computer are sat idle.  I suspect a bug in Visual Studio to be honest, as a manual code analysis takes very little time to complete.

Comment: send this to Microsoft via IDE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx

Comment: Good idea, I will do that.  Thanks!